# Submit button not working with Django template

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-templates

Here I am using Django 3.0 and Python 3.7

In my Django template When using forms my submit is not triggering and no action is not performing

Here is  my views.py

```
def sendmail(request):
    company={}
    form = JobEmailDataForm()
    client = request.user.client
    client_id = request.user.client.id
    email_data = JobEmailData.objects.filter(client_id=client)
    for i in email_data:
        reminderstatus = i.reminder_status
        bookingstatus = i.booking_today_status
        purchasing_officer = i.purchasing_officer
    bookedby = request.user
    
    client_data = Client.objects.filter(id=client_id)
  
    for val in client_data:
      
        company['name']=val.name
        company['phone']=val.phone
        company['email']=val.email
        company['replay_to_email']=val.replay_to_email or ''
        company['website']=val.website
        company['logo'] = val.logo_url
    company['address'] = get_client_address(client)
    return render(request, 'core/job_email_form_1.html', locals())
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class JobEmailDataForm(forms.Form):
    name       = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Company Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    address    = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Company Address', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    phone      = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Company Phone', widget=Html5TelephoneInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    website    = forms.URLField(max_length=100, label='Company Website', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    email      = forms.EmailField(label='Company Email', widget=Html5EmailInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    replay_to_email = forms.EmailField(label='Send from Email (Optional)', required=False, widget=Html5EmailInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    purchasing_officer = forms.EmailField(label='Purchasing Officer Email', required=False, widget=Html5EmailInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    logo       = forms.ImageField(label='Image', required=False)
    confirmation = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Additional Booking Confirmation Message', widget=forms.Textarea)
    amendments = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Additional Booking Amendments Message', widget=forms.Textarea)
    cancellation = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Additional Booking Cancellation Message', widget=forms.Textarea)
    booking_today = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Additional Booking today Message', widget=forms.Textarea)
    reminder = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Additional Booking Reminders Message', widget=forms.Textarea)
    
    reminder_status   = forms.ChoiceField(choices=REMINDER_CHOICES,label='Reminders Message Settings',)
    booking_today_status   = forms.ChoiceField(choices=REMINDER_CHOICES,label='Booking Today Message Settings',)
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            "confirmation": forms.TextInput,
        }
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'phone', 'website','email', 'replay_to_email' , 'logo','confirmation','amendments','cancellation','reminder','is_email_customer','is_email_user','reminder_status']
```

Here is my job_email.html

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span6 offset1">

        <!-- START non-filtered -->

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="/saveemaildata/">

                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}

                {{ hidden }}

                {% endfor %}

                <fieldset class="add">

                    <br><br>

                    
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

                        <div class="control-group">

                            <label class="control-label pull-left" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

                            <div class="controls" style="margin-left: 0px;">

                                {{ field }} {% if field.label == 'Send from Email (Optional)' %}{% if client.email_validated_status == 'processed' or client.email_validated_status == 'Approved by client' %} Processed <a href="#EmailValidateModal" data-toggle="modal">Check now</a> {% elif client.email_validated_status == 'Validated' %} Validated<a href="#EmailValidateModal" data-toggle="modal">Check now</a> {% elif client.email_validated_status == 'Pending' %} Validate - <a href="#EmailValidateModal" data-toggle="modal">Check how</a> {% endif  %}{% endif  %}

                            </div> 
                            <p>{{ field.help_text }}</p>

                        </div>

                        {% endfor %}
                       

                    

                </fieldset>


                <div id="form-buttons-container" class="form-actions">

                    <div class="controls">

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Update JobEmails">

                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url "roles_list" %}">Cancel</a>

                        {% if role %}

                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url "roles_delete" role.pk %}">Delete role</a>

                        

                        {% endif %}

                    </div> <!--/form-actions-->

                </div>

            </form>
            .....
            .....
            .....
 </div> <!-- /row -->
```

Here my submit button is not working I couldn't understand where I am wrong

Here is my urls.py

```
re_path(r'^saveemaildata/$',savejob,name='save_email_data'),
```

Here is my saveemail view.py

```
def savejob(request):
    messages = []
    client = request.user.client
    if request.POST:
        companyName = request.POST['name']
        companyAddress = request.POST['address']
        companyPhone = request.POST['phone']
        companyWebsite = request.POST['website']
        companyEmail = request.POST['email']
        replay_to_email = request.POST['replay_to_email']
        purchasing_officer = request.POST['purchasing_officer']
        Confirmation = request.POST['confirmation']
        Amendments = request.POST['amendments']
        Cancellation = request.POST['cancellation']
        Reminder = request.POST['reminder']
        Bookingtoday = request.POST['booking_today']
        reminder_status = request.POST['reminder_status']
        booking_today_status = request.POST['booking_today_status']
        client_id = ClientUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)[0].client_id
        doc = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
        errors = []

        import sys, traceback

        if replay_to_email:
            if doc.replay_to_email != replay_to_email:
                doc.email_validated_status = 'Pending'
                send_email_validate.delay(request.user, 1)
        doc.name = companyName
        doc.replay_to_email = replay_to_email
        doc.email = companyEmail
        doc.phone = companyPhone
        doc.website = companyWebsite

        if 'logo' in request.FILES:
            doc.logo_url = request.FILES['logo']
            print("DOC LOGO URL IS",doc.logo_url)
            doc.logo_url.storage = S3Boto3Storage(bucket_name='lightdegree')
            print("DOC LOGO URLLL",doc.logo_url.storage)
        else:
            errors.append("There is no document specified")
    doc.save()
    template = 'core/savejob.html'
    objclient =  Client.objects.get(name=companyName,email=companyEmail)
    clientid = objclient.id
    email_data = JobEmailData.objects.filter(client_id=clientid)
    if not email_data:
        objemail = JobEmailData(name = companyName,phone=companyPhone,
            website=companyWebsite,client_id=clientid,
            address=companyAddress,
            confirmation=Confirmation,amendments=Amendments,
            cancellation=Cancellation,reminder=Reminder,booking_today=Bookingtoday,
            purchasing_officer=purchasing_officer,reminder_status=reminder_status,booking_today_status=booking_today_status)
        objemail.save()
    else:        
        objemail = JobEmailData.objects.filter(client_id=clientid).update(name = companyName,phone=companyPhone,
            website=companyWebsite,
            address=companyAddress,
            confirmation=Confirmation,amendments=Amendments,
            cancellation=Cancellation,reminder=Reminder,booking_today=Bookingtoday,
            purchasing_officer=purchasing_officer,reminder_status=reminder_status,booking_today_status=booking_today_status)
    messages.append('Job emails successfully updated')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/job_emails/')
```

How can i make  my submit button to work and where i am wrong

Comment: Could you share more info? Such as views and forms, to better understand the issue and try to help out :)

Comment: I have edited my question and added views and forms please check now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I think you're missing the form tag.

Template of a minimal HTML form (django):

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Let me know if it worked out! It does for me :)**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , No its not working for me.My savejob view is not triggering  when I click submit button